# .NET Core 2.1 - Setting Azure Insights sampling configuration results in NPE

Tags: c#, azure, dependency-injection, azure-application-insights

I have an Azure Function App for which I try to configure Azure Insights Sampling (as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling), but this results in the following error:

A host error has occurred
[5/2/19 9:42:42 AM] Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: provider

I have included the following code:

```
public class StartUp : IWebJobsStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
    {
        Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions.ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions aiOptions = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions.ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions();
        aiOptions.EnableAdaptiveSampling = false;
        builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(aiOptions);
    }
}
```

Where/how/by whom should "provider" be set?

I have tried to add

```
        aiOptions.InstrumentationKey = "[MyKey]";
```

as well, but this results in the same error

Comment: NPE? NullReferenceException?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For azure function sampling, you can set it in host.json, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#configure-sampling):

v2 function:

```
{
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond" : 20
      }
    }
  }
}
```

v1 function:

```
{
  "applicationInsights": {
    "sampling": {
      "isEnabled": true,
      "maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond" : 5
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Karel, if the answer works, please help mark it as an answer. Thanks.